# Xen doesn't boot after install

Tags: raid, xen, lvm, boot, installation

I tried to setup Xen by the [instruction](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Citrix_XenServer/en) released on the site of my hoster.

I installed Xen, completed RAID setup as it is told in the instruction.
Rebooted and succesfully connected to Xen from XenCenter.
Then I created a volume for ISO and added some images to it.
Up to this point everything was OK.
But then I rebooted again - and it didn't boot!
The boot from disk doesn't start because it can't find bootloader.

I checked with mdadm status of raid - all partition are active.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should debug the boot partitions / boot process with a live cd. It is quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

Since you just started, and haven't provided details other than "as told in the instruction", I'd start over.

Sorry if that's not what you want to hear.